# How can an outsourcing platform share payment among contributors of a project with Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

There is an outsourcing platform that needs to design a payment system. It needs to receive payments and send them to all contributors of the project. These contributors may come from all over the world. Stripe provides the `Separate Charges and Transfers` solution to split a payment and send it to all contributors, but `Stripe` limits the use of the `Separate Charges and Transfers` solution to be at the same country. Are there any other solutions that can be used?

In addition, if the platform itself acts as the recipient of all payments, collects all payments, records the participants' earnings, then pays them from the platform account when they manually withdraw their reward, is there a suitable Stripe solution for this? Would this face legal issues with holding funds?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your platform account is located [cross-border transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-capabilities#transfers-cross-border) may have some limitations. Fund flow can be tricky so I would recommend talking to Stripe Support directly as they can confirm if your use-case is supported.